# FFMPEG stop live stream to Youtube

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, streaming, rtmp, mediasoup

I have a problem...FFMPEG starts live streaming at Youtube live and arround 20 to 40 seconds it stop to recording.
My terminal print :

> Delay between the first packet and last packet in the muxing queue
> is 10008000 > 10000000: forcing output